# React, updating state in reducer causes all components to re-render

Tags: reactjs

I built a react application that manage a list of items, each item has a name (so far). the app shows the tree of items on the left panel and when you double click an item a tab is opened on the right panel to edit this item details.
I am using a reducer to update the state via actions.
here is my reducer and initial state (State.js):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import io from "socket.io-client";

export const initialState = {
    items: null,
    tabs: [], // list of items opened in tabs
    active: null, // active item id (active tab)
    socket: null,
};

export const ActionType = {
    CONNECT: "connect",
    SET_ITEMS: "set_items",
    ADD_ITEM: "add_item",
    UPDATE_ITEM: "update_item",
    DELETE_ITEM: "delete_item",
    OPEN_TAB: "open_tab",
    CLOSE_TAB: "close_tab",
    SET_ACTIVE: "set_active",
    SET_ITEM_VALUE: "set_item_value",
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.CONNECT: {
            if (!state.settings.server) {
                return state;
            }
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            updated.socket = io.connect(state.settings.server);
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.SET_ITEMS: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            updated.items = action.payload;
            const _updateParent = (item) => {
                let local = localStorage.getItem("item_" + item._id);
                if (local) {
                    local = JSON.parse(local);
                    const itemParent = item.parent; // save parent
                    item = _.assign(item, local); // override from local
                    item.parent = itemParent; // restore parent
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < item.items.length; i++) {
                    item.items[i].parent = item;
                    _updateParent(item.items[i]);
                }
            };
            for (let i = 0; i < updated.items.length; i++) {
                _updateParent(updated.items[i]);
            }
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.ADD_ITEM: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const item = action.payload;
            if (item.parent) {
                const parentItem = findTreeItem(updated.items, item.parent);
                item.parent = parentItem;
                parentItem.items.push(item);
            } else {
                // collection
                updated.items.push(item);
            }
            item.items = [];
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.OPEN_TAB: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const alreadyOpened = updated.tabs.find((item) => item._id === action.payload._id);
            if (!alreadyOpened) {
                updated.tabs.push(action.payload);
            }
            updated.active = action.payload._id;
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.CLOSE_TAB: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const closedId = _.get(updated.tabs[action.payload], "_id");
            updated.tabs.splice(action.payload, 1);
            if (updated.tabs.length === 0) {
                updated.active = null;
            } else if (updated.active === closedId) {
                updated.active = updated.tabs[0]._id;
            }
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.SET_ACTIVE: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            updated.active = action.payload;
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.SET_ITEM_VALUE: {
            const updated = state; //{ ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const item = action.payload.item;
            if (item) {
                _.set(item, action.payload.path, action.payload.value);
                if (action.payload.path !== "modified") {
                    item.modified = true;
                }
            }
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.UPDATE_ITEM: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const updatedItem = action.payload;
            const oldItem = findTreeItem(updated.items, updatedItem._id);
            const oldItemParent = oldItem.parent;
            Object.assign(oldItem, updatedItem);
            oldItem.parent = oldItemParent;
            oldItem.modified = false;
            return updated;
        }
        case ActionType.DELETE_ITEM: {
            const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
            const deletedItem = action.payload;
            updated.socket.emit("delete-item", deletedItem._id);
            return updated;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const StateContext = React.createContext({});
```

and the tabs container component: (TabsContainer.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";

import { StateContext, ActionType } from "../../State";
import TabTitle from "./TabTitle";

export default function TabsContainer() {
    const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(StateContext);

    return (
        <>
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                {state.tabs.map((t, i) => (
                    <li key={i} className="nav-item">
                        <a className={"nav-link user-select-none " + classnames({ active: state.active === t._id })}>
                            <TabTitle item={t} tabIndex={i} />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <div className="tab-content flex-grow-1" id="nav-tabContent">
                {state.tabs.map((t, i) => (
                    <div
                        key={i}
                        className={
                            "tab-pane h-100 fade" +
                            classnames({
                                show: state.active === t._id,
                                active: state.active === t._id,
                            })
                        }
                        role="tabpanel"
                    >
                        <ItemTab item={t} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

and the item tab component (ItemTab.js):

```
import React from "react";
import ItemName from "./general/ItemName";

export default function ItemTab({ item }) {
    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column py-2">
            <div className="flex-fill">
                <ItemName item={item} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

the item name component (ItemName.js):

```
import React from "react";

import { StateContext, ActionType } from "../../State";
import ActionButton from "./ActionButton";

export default function ItemName({ item }) {
    const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(StateContext);

    return (
        <div className="row border-bottom border-secondary pb-2">
            <div className="col-8">
                <div className="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span className="input-group-text">Name</span>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                            dispatch({
                                type: ActionType.SET_ITEM_VALUE,
                                payload: {
                                    item,
                                    path: "name",
                                    value: e.target.value,
                                },
                            })
                        }
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-4 text-end">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ActionButton actionColor="success" actionText="Save locally" loadingText="Saving..." action={saveItemLocallyAction} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The app is working as expected but my problem is that all components are re-rendered when trying to edit any item name, you can notice it blinks, when u update the item name, it is updated directly on the left tree and on the tab title.
please advise how to overcome this re-rendering issue and what pattern should I use?

tried to use other hooks like useCallback, useMemo, useEffect but could not fix it

EDIT:
here is an image after rewriting the cases in my reducer, you can see in the console the re-rendering issue:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyh7O.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you always return `updated` variable, which has previously been mutated in the state (by the excessive use of `=` assignment operator).

Try re-writing your reducer cases.

Turn them from this:

```js
// State.js
case ActionType.UPDATE_ITEM: {
  const updated = { ...state }; //_.cloneDeep(state);
  const updatedItem = action.payload;
  const oldItem = findTreeItem(updated.items, updatedItem._id);
  const oldItemParent = oldItem.parent;
  Object.assign(oldItem, updatedItem);
  oldItem.parent = oldItemParent;
  oldItem.modified = false;
  return updated;
}
```

into this:

```js
case ActionType.UPDATE_ITEM: {
  // write socket-specific instructions here if you need them, since I've seen you use sockets in your app
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((item) => {
      // `updated` and `updatedItem` not needed, but you can assign them if they make the job easier
      const oldItem = findTreeItem(state.items, action.payload._id);
      const oldItemParent = oldItem.parent;
      Object.assign(oldItem, action.payload);
      oldItem.parent = oldItemParent;
      oldItem.modified = false;
      return item;      
    })
  }
}
```

Good luck with the app and don't forget to have fun :D

Comment: I tried rewriting the cases in my reducer as you suggested, but unfortunately did not fix it. here is my updated code for the case when updating an item name: `case ActionType.SET_ITEM_VALUE: {
   const updatedItem = action.payload.item;
   return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((item) => {
     if (updatedItem && updatedItem._id === item._id) {
      _.set(item, action.payload.path, action.payload.value);
      if (action.payload.path !== "modified") {
       item.modified = true;
      }
     }
     return item;
    }),
   };
  }`, attached image for the new result